# LINQ - Left outer join to attach list to parent object

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
List<Company> companies;
List<Product> products;
```

I want to attach the relevant Product objects whose CompanyID matches the parent into the Company.Products list. Note that a Company might not necessarily have a product. What is the most performant way to do this? LINQ?

Right now I am just doing a:

```
foreach(Company c in companies)
{
    c.Products = products.Where(x => x.CompanyID == c.CompanyID).ToList();
}
```

But this is very slow!!

Class definitions for reference:

```
class Company
{
    int CompanyID;
    string Name;
    List<Product> Products;
}

class Product
{
    int ProductID;
    int CompanyID;
    string ProductName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can do this by using `GroupJoin`:

```
companies
    .GroupJoin(products, c => c.CompanyID, p => p.CompanyID, (c, pg) => 
        new Company
        {
            Products = pg.ToList(),
            CompanyID = c.CompanyID
            //other properties
        });
```

`GroupJoin` uses hash matching so it's more efficient than nested loops.

To append those values you can simply do this:

```
var companiesWithProducts = companies
    .GroupJoin(products, c => c.CompanyID, p => p.CompanyID, (c, pg) => 
        new { Company = c, Products = pg });

foreach (var p in companiesWithProducts)
{
    p.Company.Products = p.Products.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is like 50 times faster. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this using the Extension Methods, instead of the linq query syntax would be like this:

```
var results = companies.Join(products,
  c => c.CompanyID,
  p => p.CompanyID,
  (Company,Product) => new {Company.CompanyID, Product.ToList()}
);
```